# Create event into MariaDB

Tags: sql, mariadb

I try to create a event schedule everyday at 16:34:00. Execute each command one by one, all work correctly. But when I create the event it doesn't work.

I found than SQL query has no execute order but I'm not sure the issue come from here.

```
CREATE EVENT spip3
    ->     ON SCHEDULE
    ->       EVERY 1 DAY
    ->     STARTS '2018-03-14 16:34:00'
    ->     DO
    ->       BEGIN
    ->         set @value = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
    ->         SET @date = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE spip_evenements ALTER date_debut SET DEFAULT "', @value, '";')
    ->         PREPARE stmt FROM @date
    ->         EXECUTE stmt
    ->         DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt
    ->       END;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @date = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE spip_evenements ALTER date_debut SET DEFAULT "',' at line 8
```

Comment: missing semicolons?

Comment: If I put semicolons, it end my event creation. How can I do?

Comment: put a semicolon after `set @value = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`. what happens?

Comment: `CREATE EVENT spip3
    ->         .........
    ->         set @value = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7
`

Comment: If I remove the `BEGIN` no more error but it close my event creation.

`   ...  ->         set @value = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about my ignorance, I haven't define any delimiter.

```
delimiter |
CREATE EVENT spip3
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 1 DAY
    STARTS '2018-03-14 16:34:00'
    DO
        set @value = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
        SET @date = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE spip_evenements ALTER date_debut SET DEFAULT "', @value, '";');
        PREPARE stmt FROM @date;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END |

delimiter ;
```